# React Native - trying to extract the data and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB6Bu.png)I am new to react-native. I was trying to access the API using fetch. I was able to print the result on the console but was unable to print on a mobile screen. I have attached the screenshot of the practice code below.
[enter image description here][2]

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'

const getMoviesFromApi = () => {
  //GET request
  fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    //Request Type
    //method: 'POST',
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    //If response is in json then in success
    .then((responseJson) => {
      //Success
     // alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      //console.log(responseJson);
      return responseJson;
    })
}

const App = () => {
    let data = getMoviesFromApi()
    console.log(data)

     return (

        <SafeAreaView>
          <Text> JSON.stringify{data} </Text>

          {/* <Text> JSON.stringify{parseData} </Text> */}
        </SafeAreaView>
     )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an `useState` and keep the data you receive from the api inside state, and `useEffect` to fetch the data when state updates so will the UI

So I would use something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      const data = await getMoviesFromApi();
      setMovies(data); // I supose it's an array of movies
    }
  }, [getMoviesFromApi])

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. So, I did  <Text> JSON.stringify{data} </Text> inside the return function and it throws an error. So, I was wondering what did I do wrong?

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` what structure do you have?

Comment: In any case you want to map over your array and and output the JSX that you want.
For example: 
`return (<>movies.map(movie => (<Text>movie.name</Text>))</>)`